# http get dealing with 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, get

This function is supposed to return data when everything is fine and return 0 when it receives a 404 error.

```
function httpGet(url)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==404)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false );
        xmlhttp.send();    
    }
```

For example,

```
username = '_ele';
httpGet('https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/'+username+'/followers');
```

would throw a 404 error but I want the function to be returning the value 0 instead, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this version

```
function httpGet(url)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false );
        xmlhttp.send();    
        if (xmlhttp.status != 200) {
          // catch error
          return xmlhttp.status + ': ' + xmlhttp.statusText; // expample error: 404: Not Found
        } else {
          // response
          return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfrhh6kw/ the console still throws the 404 error, what can i do about that?

Comment: U will recieve errors in console too, but your code in jsfiddle working (I recieve alert 505) and after if rewrite `return xmlhttp.status + ': ' + xmlhttp.statusText;` to `return "ook"` I recieve alert with text `ook`